# Symfony 2 one to many relationship not mapping

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 Entities: OwnerProperty,OwnerPropertyIntl. I declared a relationship between OwnerProperty and OwnerPropertyIntl. 
I use this command `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`, 
and result: `[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.`
But when i get data by

At file OwnerProperty

```
    /**
     * One-To-Many, Bidirectional
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $ownerPropertyIntl
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OwnerPropertyIntl", mappedBy="ownerProperty", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $ownerPropertyIntl;

   /**
     * Add owner_property_intl
     *
     * @param OwnerPropertyIntl $ownerPropertyIntl
     * @return OwnerProperty
     */
    public function addOwnerPropertyIntl(OwnerPropertyIntl $ownerPropertyIntl)
    {
        $this->ownerPropertyIntl[] = $ownerPropertyIntl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove owner_property_intl
     *
     * @param OwnerPropertyIntl $ownerPropertyIntl
     */
    public function removePropertyIntl(OwnerPropertyIntl $ownerPropertyIntl)
    {
        $this->ownerPropertyIntl->removeElement($ownerPropertyIntl);
    }

    /**
     * Get owner_property_intl
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOwnerPropertyIntl()
    {
        return $this->ownerPropertyIntl;
    }
```

`$ownerProperty = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ACMWebBundle:OwnerProperty')->find(123);`

and dump this data:
[image]

No data for ownerPropertyIntl, although database have 4 records of ownerPropertyIntl with owner_property_id = 123.

Please help me.

Comment: You haven't asked for the relation (`getOwnerPropertyIntl`) in your code yet, thus the field is not populated, just a proxy object. Try dumping `$ownerProperty->getOwnerPropertyIntl()`

Comment: I try dump `$ownerProperty->getOwnerPropertyIntl()` but null. How to ask for the relation  (getOwnerPropertyIntl) @Fracsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either call getOwnerPropertyIntl() as stated by Fracsi, which will trigger a new SQL query, or you can set FETCH=EAGER on your relationship, which will always pull out the second entity as well.
An example is provided [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone)

Unless you really want lazy loading, you should always use eager strategy.

Comment: Thanks you. This solved my problem. But i have too much entity and to much relationship. I want set default `FETCH=EAGER` for all Relationship. Do you have any way?

Comment: I do not see any parameter for this in http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Probably because there is a rare scenario when all queries should use either eager or lazy loading. Usually you must analyze each of your queries and decide which use what.

Comment: I wouldn't set `FETCH=EAGER` on all of your entities and relationships - it could lead to expensive joins in situations where you don't need.  You're better off creating specific queries as you need them and manually joining when necessary.

Comment: But All entities not problem,the problem occurred only after add 2 entities OwnerProperty,OwnerPropertyIntl.